# How to make gcc and clang c++ binary use absolute library path on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, profiling

Typical dynamically linked programs loads linked libraries by conducting file resolution or file searches from Library paths via `ld-*.so`. This search process is typically expensive especially if there are a lot of libraries in the Library paths and there are a lot of libraries to be loaded.

Compile time has already resolved this dependency, now, why would it bother to search these libraries again? In one program I profiled, `ld-*.so` consumed 70% of CPU time, that would be one heck of a BIG bottleneck!

So, I would like to turn off this file search conducted via `ld-*.so` by using the absolute/static path to the libraries instead, this way, any calls will go directly to where it should be. How do I do this for specific program I am compiling?

Comment: It's only a big bottleneck in small quick-running programs. In a long running program the time spent loading libraries approaches zero. Furthermore, in a small quick-running program, can you even measure the actual time the system is loading shared libraries? The little *actual* time spent searching for and loading shared libraries is still barely measurable. If you want to optimize, optimize where it actually matters instead.

Comment: It is a big program, I can say that the main Executable is 3 MB while the rest of its other files were several hundred of MB and I want to fix that thing.

Comment: Why do you think that ld.so spends most of the time _searching_ for the libraries? Have you tried some strace to see search misses? I bet that the overhead you see is not in the searching but in the real symbol resolving and other things that you can't avoid.

Comment: because oprofile said that it consumed 70% of all execution of the program  I run. That 70% is from ld*.so only and nothing else.

Comment: Again, _searching_ for libraries is just one minor function of what ld.so does, so even if you reduce that overhead (and, basically, with proper ld.so.cache for glibc you don't have it already), it won't solve your problem. Have you tried [prelinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink) your binaries, BTW?

Comment: so, how do I solve ld*so consuming 70% of cpu time?

Comment: Prelinking, as mentioned above. And/or if the libraries you're talking about come from your own project, especially if we're talking about C++, then you might be interested in [this link about visibility option](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and [this classic work](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) on libraries in general.

Comment: 70% of CPU time could be quite small, if for example CPU time is 10% of wall-clock time. If it were, that would only be 7% of overall time. If you could reduce it to *zero* (which you can't), the whole thing would go from 10 seconds (say) to 9.3 seconds. Is it worth the trouble? The linker *should* be I/O bound, so its CPU time should be a small fraction of its wall-clock time.

Comment: when I profiled it, it even went to 70-80% the whole time it is running. I can say, the whole time of 30 mins, so that would take about 21 mins being wasted to this thing. It should have been only under 10% or less of the whole runtime.